# Retrieve row number based on value in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know the exact row number and I'm using this code

```
DataRow[] resultsize = dt.Select("psize like '%" + hdncurrentsize.Value + "%'");
```

but result is always `1` but not the exact matching row number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in knowing the row position,You can try this

```
DataRow[] resultsize = dt.Select("psize like '%" + hdncurrentsize.Value + "%'");

foreach(var row in resultsize){    
   var idx = dt.Rows.IndexOf<DataRow>(row);    
}
```

Or

```
DataRow[] allRows;    
dt.Rows.CopyTo(allRows,0);

foreach(var row in resultsize){    
   var idx = Array.FindIndex<DataRow>
                   (allRows, (item) => { return item == row; });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me on this. it worked for me. great efforts

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct. Why are you sure, that number of returned rows is wrong?

Also you can use [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386977.aspx) for filtering rows (it will do the same as your `DataTable.Select`, but is more readable strongly-typed manner)

```
var rows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
           where row.Field<string>("psize").Contains(hdncurrentsize.Value)
           select row;

int resultSize = rows.Count();
```

*BTW* what type has `hdncurrentsize.Value` is it a string (I assume it is)?

*UPDATE* thus you were searching for row indexes (code below will loop through datatable only once, without searching index for each found row after filtering):

```
var indexes = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
                .Where(x => x.row.Field<string>("psize").Contains(hdncurrentsize.Value))
                .Select(x => x.index);
```

Comment: 1 item1 L 20,
             1 item1 M 20,
             1 item1 S 20

in above table (3 rows) if i want to get row no for 'S' then should row no is 2 but it not getting exactly as i want

Comment: So, `psize` field has a string type, and possible values `L`, `M`, and `S`. What is type of `hdncurrentsize.Value`?

Comment: if hdncurrentsize.value contains in 3rd row then it should rows count 2 but not working

Comment: hdncurrentsize.Value its a string

Comment: @GopalRohila again, what are possible values of `psize` field? `1 item1 L 20` is whole row values, or it is field value?

Comment: its a field value like id, product, size, price